# problem while executing react-native run android

Tags: react-native

While upgrading the react-native app to androidx I have created a react-native.config.js file with the following code :

```js
module.exports = { 
  project: { 
    ios: {}, 
    android: {}, 
  }, 
  assets: ['./path-to-assets'], 
  commands: require('./path-to-commands.js'), 
}; 

module.exports = { 
  dependency: { 
    platforms: { 
      ios: {}, 
      android: {}, 
    }, 
    assets: ['./path-to-assets'], 
    hooks: { 
      prelink: './path-to-a-prelink-hook', 
    }, 
  }, 
}; 

module.exports = { 
  platforms: { 
    windows: require('./local-cli/platform.js').windows, 
  }, 
};
```

now react-native run-android command is not working,

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I cannot see your code. Add a code.

Comment: module.exports = {
    project: {
      ios: {},
      android: {}, 
    },
    assets: ['./path-to-assets'],
    commands: require('./path-to-commands.js'), 
  };
  module.exports = {
    dependency: {
      platforms: {
        ios: {},
        android: {},
      },
      assets: ['./path-to-assets'],
      hooks: {
        prelink: './path-to-a-prelink-hook',
      },
    },
  };
  module.exports = {
    platforms: {
      windows: require('./local-cli/platform.js').windows,
    },
  };

Comment: What error occurs?